# how is this border effect achieved best with CSS?

Tags: css, styles, border, stylesheet

I saw an amazing border effect on a website, and I'm wondering how the effect is achieved best. It's a seperator between navigation items in a vertical list:

[image: Border effect]

I will choose the best answer based on the cross-browser compatibilty (and as non-hacky as possible).

Comment: Are you trying to just do the line, or do you want the middle white glow effect too?

Comment: The glow effect of course.

Comment: If you want something that's fully compatible you're going to need to use an image... but it can be done with css, just figuring that out now...

Comment: image is broken, can't see anything other than a black square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/h9kMA/1/)

You may have to mess with it depending on what you want to put inside you list! If you want to change the color of the glow, you can just alter the colors in the gradient. [This is a nice generator, which you probably already knew about.](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
}
li {
    background: rgb(30,30,30);
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    color: rgb(140,140,140);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #1e1e1e; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1e1e1e 0%, #757575 50%, #1e1e1e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1e1e1e), color-stop(50%,#757575), color-stop(100%,#1e1e1e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1e1e1e 0%,#757575 50%,#1e1e1e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1e1e1e 0%,#757575 50%,#1e1e1e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1e1e1e 0%,#757575 50%,#1e1e1e 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #1e1e1e 0%,#757575 50%,#1e1e1e 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e1e1e', endColorstr='#1e1e1e',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```